# How to insert unique value into non-identity field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to do an insert into an established table which has a primary key fields and another field (call it field1) that is unique (this other unique field has a unique constraint preventing my inserts).  Field1 is not an identity field, so it does NOT autonumber.  Unfortunately I can't change the table.  Existing inserts are made using code to increment and all involve looping/cursors.  Something like SELECT MAX(field1) + 1

So, is there anyway to do this insert without looping/cursor?  This field means nothing to me, but there are already 500,000+ records using their silly numbering scheme, so I must respect that.

This is simplified (ReceiptNumber is the field I want to insert unique), but:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

Begin Transaction TransMain
Declare @nvErrMsg nvarchar(4000)

--Insert inventory receipts
Insert Into Avanti_InventoryReceipts ( 
    ReceiptNumber , ItemNumber , ReceiptDate , OrderNumber , JobNumber , Supplier ,
    LineNumber , MultiLineNumber , [Status] , QtyOrdered , QtyReceived , QtyToReceive ,
    QtyBackOrdered , Cost , Wholesale , LastCost , QtyToInvoice , QtyUsed ,
    ReferenceNumber , [Description] , SupplierType , Processed , DateExpected , DateReceived , 
    AccountNumber , Reference2 , EmployeeCode , ExtraCode , Location , RollNumber , 
    QtyIssues , Notes , NumPackages , BundleSize , ConsignmentUnitPrice , RecFromProduction , 
    QtyCommitted )
SELECT ( SELECT MAX(ReceiptNumber) + 1 FROM Avanti_inventoryReceipts ) , CR.ItemNumber , Convert(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) , PONum , 'FL-INV' , PH.POVendor ,
    0 , 0 , 'O' , CR.QtyOrdered , QtyReceivedToday , QtyReceivedToday ,
    Case @closePO 
         When 'N' Then Case When ( QtyOrdered - QtyReceivedToday ) < 0 Then 0 Else ( QtyOrdered - QtyReceivedToday) End 
         When 'Y' Then 0
         Else 0 End     
          , PD.TransCost * QtyReceivedToday , IH.PriceWholeSale , IH.CostLast , QtyReceivedToday , 0 ,
    '' , PODetailDescription , '' , '' , '' , Convert(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) , 
    '' , '' , @employeeCode , '' , 'F L E X O' , '' , 
    0 , 'Flexo Materials' , 0 , 0 , 0 , '' , 0
FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData CR
LEFT JOIN Avanti_PODetails PD ON CR.PONum = PD.PONumber
LEFT JOIN Avanti_POHeader PH ON CR.PONum = PH.PONumber
LEFT JOIN Avanti_InventoryHeader IH ON CR.ItemNumber = IH.ItemNumber


  IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    Begin
      Select @nvErrMsg = 'Error entering into [InventoryReceipts] -' +  [description]
        From master..sysmessages
     Where [error] = @@ERROR

     RAISERROR ( @nvErrMsg , 16, 1 )
     Goto Err_
   End

  Commit Transaction TransMain
  Goto Exit_


Err_:

   Rollback Transaction TransMain

Exit_:

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Comment: Do you need to insert these rows one-by-one, or in bulk?

Comment: @Branko -My question specifically states no looping, so bulk.

Comment: I'm going to add a field to FI_CurrentReceiptData which will be uniquely numbered starting from 0.  I will number it from client code.  This is messy, but looks like the best I can do within the established system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an autonumber starting from 0 in client code and passed that in.  Now I'm adding that value to the max receiptnumber to get a unique one.  Also, I realized I already had an identity column in FI_CurrentReceiptData, but I didn't want to use that one because it won't start at 0 for each receipt set, and reseeding the identity each time seems like a waste of processor time.

Comment: I smell a potential concurrency issue... Is it possible that other sessions will insert new rows after you seed your "identity" in client code?

Comment: @DanO -I don't see that as possible in this situation.  Only 1 person at a time is receiving anything using the program.  And even if more than 1 person were to receive at a time, the receipt number insert would fail, so no concurrency, just annoyed users.  In this use case I think I"m ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
insert into mytable (field1, field2, ...)
values (( SELECT MAX(field1) + 1 from mytable), 'value2', ...);
```

Comment: What is your source for these new rows? Another table?

Comment: @Aaron -Yes, coming from another table.

Comment: What if there is concurrency?

Comment: @Aaron -I'm running this in a transaction, does that save me?  Would really love for something this simple to work.

Comment: Can you add to the question a formatted version of the query you're actually running? I'm trying to reproduce and I'd like to be clear what you're doing.

Comment: @Aaron -Can you elaborate on the possible problem you see here?

Comment: What happens if someone else tries to insert? Do you think if they get through it might affect your `MAX + 1` calculation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3102/discussion-between-maw74656-and-aaron-bertrand)

Answer (score 0):

Why not looping? It should be quite efficient.

Since you already have a UNIQUE constraint on the field, you can:

- Simply try to insert `MAX(field1) + 1`. Since there is index on UNIQUE field, `MAX` is fast.
- If its passes, great you are done.
- If it fails (which will typically be manifested as an exception in your client code), just try again until you succeed.

Most of the time, the INSERT will succeed right away. In rare instances where a concurrent user tries to insert the same value, you'll handle that gracefully by trying the "next" value.

Comment: Looping may not be fast when it involves lots of round trips to the database.

Comment: @Andrew Unless the workload is extremely heavy, looping won't cause lots of round-trips to the database - insert will likely succeed on the first iteration, thus incurring only one round-trip.

Comment: @Branko -What if it keeps failing?  How many times can I try?  Seems awkward, there must be a better way.

Comment: @MAW74656 It can't keep failing. It will succeed sooner or later, probably sooner, as explained in my answer. BTW, my answer was specifically geared toward scenario in which several parallel clients insert rows one-by-one. Now that I see that you actually need bulk-insert and you don't care for concurrency much, just taking an exclusive table lock (as suggested by Aaron Bertrand) is probably the best solution.